# How can I automate the setup of development tools for new hires?

Tags: configuration, ide, development-environment, provisioning

I am looking in a way to have some kind of "image" (VM, Vagrant box, Docker container...???) with all the development tools needed to work on our software project, like a configured IDE (i.e. Eclipse or PyCharm), build and deployment tools.

After a bit of searching I found surprising little about this topic, while plenty about development environments that mirrors the production one. Almost every source I found considers installing development tools on the host, while deploying in a virtualized environment.

The first thing that comes to my mind is a virtual machine of some sort, maybe provisioned in an automated way (Packer + Ansible maybe). I have also seen some blog posts about running GUI applications in Docker containers via X.org.

Is there a better way? How did you solve the problem?

The ultimate goal is to let new hires being productive in hours instead of days.

UPDATE: After some research, I am currently evaluating:

1. Development in a Virtual Machine
2. Development with the support of Docker containers
3. Cloud IDEs

Answer (score 1):

Have your IT department make an image of a development laptop and then use a confluence page for tweaking the images to the needs of the individual developer. Then use docker images for setting up any servers they will need. These can be run on the laptops. You can use docker swarm to have many docker images spun up if you need it.

Comment: "`++` ..."  And it would be delightful if you could, say, add some URL-links pointing to "must-read" articles about these technologies.

Comment: I agree. Later today I'll add some.

Comment: Good advice, but hardly applicable on developer's personal laptops or home machines. Thanks anyway

Comment: Ah well I rarely get to have personal laptops. IT controls the hardware and what can be ON the network - period. That's actually been the norm once you get past a certain company size.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have dev tools installed on the host so every one do it its own way and I don't want to convert someone to specific tool.

If you want to go the other route and give your new hires a ready to use dev box, I would go with vagrant working in GUI mode + provisioning scripts. For example the jhipster project has a nice [dev box](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox), its pretty nice as they have many tools to be installed, its pretty neat so after you install vagrant/virtualbox (or vmware)/git on your host you're ready in minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the JHipster pointer, very useful. I am still not convinced about developing in a VM. It may quickly eat host's resources

Comment: clear, I think its good if you want to check the stack  - but anyway as I mentioned in my answer, I still prefer to have dev tools installed on host. For example on the vagrant/jhipster you can take the provisioning part and make it for host so everything will be installed from script on the host